# prove function in product space is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function, define a function $F: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $(x,y) \rightarrow f(x-y)$, how do I show that this function is measurable? What I have tried is:

$F^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}|  f(x-y) <  \alpha \} = \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x\} \times \{y \in \mathbb{R} | f(x-y) < \alpha\}$. Since Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, the function $f_{x}: y \rightarrow f(x-y)$ is also measurable, so the set $\{y \in \mathbb{R} | f(x-y) < \alpha\}$ is measurable. The problem is that the union is not over countable set, and I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to $\Bbb{R}$, so let me provide a proof in the general case. Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, and $F:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is defined as $F(x,y):=f(x-y)$. Now, define the function $T:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^n$ as $T(x,y):= (x,x-y)$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ as $\pi_2(x,y):=y$. Then, $F=f\circ\pi_2\circ T$, so for any $A\subset\Bbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align}
F^{-1}(A)&= T^{-1}\bigg[\pi_2^{-1}[f^{-1}(A)]\bigg]= T^{-1}\bigg[\Bbb{R}^n\times f^{-1}(A)\bigg].
\end{align}
Now, if $A$ is actually a Borel set, then by definition of $f$ being Lebesgue-measurable, we have that $f^{-1}(A)$ is a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Next, the product $\Bbb{R}^n\times f^{-1}(A)$ is a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$ (this should be one of the first few things you discuss when talking about Lebesgue measure on a product space). Finally, $T$ is an invertible linear transformation, which in particular means that the function $T^{-1}$ is actually Lipschitz continuous. As a result, it maps Lebesgue-measurable sets to Lebesgue-measurable sets. Thus, $F^{-1}(A)$ is a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$, hence $F$ is Lebesgue measurable.

---

**Edit in response to comments regarding measurability**

When talking about measurability of functions, one has to be very careful to specify the $\sigma$-algebras involved; not specifying them can easily cause a lot of confusions. If $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ are measurable spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is a function, we say $f$ is $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}$-measurable (or measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$... however you want to phrase things) if the preimage of every set in $\mathcal{B}$ lies in $\mathcal{A}$, i.e $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})\subset \mathcal{A}$.

When dealing with a topological space $(Y,\tau)$, a natural choice for a $\sigma$-algebra is the one generated by $\tau$; this is called called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$, and we shall denote this as $\mathcal{B}_Y$. So, if you have $(X,\mathcal{A})$ a measurable space, and $(Y,\tau)$ a topological space, you can consider the measurable space $(Y,\mathcal{B}_Y)$ so given a function $f:X\to Y$, we can talk about $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}_Y$ measurability as I've defined above. By the way, it is a theorem (not too hard to prove) that to check a function is $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}$ measurable, it suffices to check that for some (or equivalently, for any) generating set $\mathcal{S}$ of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, we have $f^{-1}(\mathcal{S})\subset \mathcal{A}$. So, if you apply this to the situation of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a topological space, we see that saying $f:X\to Y$ is $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}_Y$ measurable is equivalent to saying preimage of every open set lies in $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e $f^{-1}(\tau)\subset \mathcal{A}$). This is precisely the definition you cite from Rudin.

So far we've talking quite generally. Let's specialize to $\Bbb{R}^n$. Well, this is a topological space, with the usual toplogy generated by (for example) the Euclidean norm. So we can consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$. This is certainly a natural choice for a $\sigma$-algebra. On the other hand, it is also quite natural to consider the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ (which you can for example define using the Caratheodory construction). Hence, we now have two fairly natural choices for $\sigma$-algebras on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (for the purposes we usually have in mind).

It is a fact that we have a strict inclusion: $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}^n}\subsetneq \mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$. So, if we now have a topological space $(Y,\tau)$, with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_Y$, and a function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to Y$, then clearly, we have two different notions of measurability. We have the notion of $\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$-$\mathcal{B}_{Y}$ measurability (for which we say $f$ is a Borel (measurable) function). We also have the notion of $\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$-$\mathcal{B}_Y$ measurabiltiy (for which we say $f$ is a Lebesgue-measurable function). So as you can see the definition of Lebesgue-measurable is slightly nuanced.

You may now wonder the following question: for functions $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$, why not define Lebesgue-measurability to mean $\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$-$\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}^m}$ measurability. Well, there aren't many such functions, because there exist even continuous functions which are not $\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}}$-$\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}}$ measurable, whereas every continuous function is $\mathcal{L}_{\Bbb{R}}$-$\mathcal{B}_{\Bbb{R}}$ measurable.

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Also it seems that we can simplify the argument by saying $T$ is continuous function, hence measurable?

Comment: @CuriousAlpaca $T$ is indeed linear hence continuous hence measurable, but that's not enough in this case. We need the fact that $T$ is linear hence locally Lipschitz, hence sends measure zero sets to measure zero sets hence sends Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets. This last part is NOT true in general for an arbitrary continuous function (otherwise, I would have just said from the beginning that $F = f\circ \text{continuous function}$ hence Lebesgue-measurable... but unfortunately this is not true and things aren't so simple).

Comment: The troublesome part of course is that composition of Lebesgue measurable functions need not be Lebesgue-measurable, which should be expected from the definition (preimage of **Borel** sets are required to be Lebesgue-measurable). If you were dealing with Borel functions then everything is much nicer because the definition of Borel-measurable is much simpler (preimage of Borel sets is Borel). So, composition of Borel functions is Borel.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused: Rudin's definition of a measurable function is a function from a measure space to a topological space such that preimage of open set is measurable, while Wikipedia's definition of a measurable function is a function from measure space to a measure space such that preimage of measurable set is measurable. How does that fit in with the definition of Lebesgue measurable function?

Comment: @CuriousAlpaca see my latest edit. Long story short: always specify the $\sigma$-algebras present when talking about measurability unless there is no chance for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is measurable by Lusin's theorem, there is a sequence of continuous functions $f_n\to f$ a.e. Since $F_n:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R/F_n(x,y)=f_n(x-y)$ is continuous, $F_n$ is measurable and $F_n\to F$ a.e. so $F$ is measurable since the limit of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: A necessary proof is if $A\subset\mathbb R$ has $0$ measure and $B=\{(x,y):x-y\in A\}$ then $B$ has $0$ measure.